# How to paginate many to many relationship in laravel using eager loading

Tags: php, laravel-5

i have team table and  member table and pivot table that has both tables.

in my controller i have the following:

$teams = Team::all();

```
   $teams->load(['members' => function ($q) {
        $q->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(6);
    }]);
```

so after i navigate into my view, it's works and shows 6 members
but when i code {{ $teams->members_paginated  }} in my view
it gives me this error

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$members_paginated (View: /var/www/html/Al Muktar/resources/views/frontend/other/committee-words.blade.php)
```

so my question how to render that many to many eager loading into my view 
like 
{{ $teams->members_paginated  }}

thanks

Comment: Which version of Laravel do you have? And why do you think `members_paginated` should be a valid call? Have you read the doc?

Comment: i use 5.3, i tried that with single record and its works, but when i returned all the teams with members, i can't do anymore pagination.,

Comment: so, i don't know if {{ $teams->members_paginated }} is works or valid with all teams and members.....its work for single team, but for all teams and members not work